# Cannot instantiate the type View.OnClickListener

Tags: android, onclicklistener

I got two error messages in my code

1.Cannot instantiate the type View.OnClickListener

2.Multiple markers at this line
    - Syntax error on token ")", ; expected
    - Syntax error on token "(", ; expected
    - void is an invalid type for the variable 
     onClick

```
package com.thebasics;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.view.View.OnClickListener;

public class menu extends Activity{

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    Button tut1 = (Button)findViewById(R.id.tutorial1);
    tut1.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener(){

        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            startActivity(new Intent("com.thebasics.TUTORIALONE"));
        }

    });
}


@Override
protected void onPause() {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    super.onPause();
}


}
```

Comment: Can you include imports and log?

Comment: looks like wrong import. check your import statement.

Answer (score 0):

Replace the `View.OnClickListener` with `OnClickListener`. 
And check whether you imported

```
   import android.view.View;
   import android.view.View.OnClickListener;
```

**EDIT**

I think you missed `@Override` before `onClick` method.

Comment: done. but still have one error

- void is an invalid type for the variable onClick

Comment: @AlvinHeng edited the answer i think you missed `@Override` add that let  see

Comment: Glad that your problem solved. If my answer helps then accept it as an answer.

Answer (score 0):

//**Cannot instantiate the type View.OnClickListener**

```
 package com.example.mysampleapp;


 import android.R.string;
 import android.os.Bundle;
 import android.app.Activity;
 import android.view.Menu;
 import android.view.View;
 import android.widget.Button;
 import android.widget.CheckBox;
 import android.widget.EditText;
 import android.widget.TextView;
 import android.widget.Toast;
 import android.view.View.OnClickListener;
 public class MainActivity extends Activity {
 TextView t;
 EditText e;
 Button b;
 String s;
 CheckBox c1,c2;




@Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    t=(TextView)findViewById(R.id.textView1);
    e=(EditText)findViewById(R.id.editText1);
    b=(Button)findViewById(R.id.button1);
    t.setText("Welcome");
    b.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener());
    c1=(CheckBox)findViewById(R.id.checkBox1);
    c2=(CheckBox)findViewById(R.id.checkBox2);
    s=e.getText().toString();
```

Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "You have entered"+s+"/n Hindi"+c2.isChecked(),Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

```
}


@Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
    // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
    getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.main, menu);
    return true;

}
```

}